# Passing a delegate to another view controller's delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I'm working to build one feature in an app written in Objective-C. I can't post code but I will try to be descriptive with my world. The problem i'm facing is related to delegates.

1. `AlphaViewController` has `ConnectionView` as one of its `delegate`. It helps to add perform some operation on data provided to `AlphaViewController` and we show output on `AlphaViewController's` view.
2. When you click on a button in `AlphaViewController`, I show an `UIAlertController`. From which I can click a button to open `ReportView`. `BetaViewController` creates `ReportView`.
3. `BetaViewController` has `ReportGenerator` as its `delegate`. `ReportGenerator` helps to generate some HTML which I render in `BetaViewController's` view.

My problem is that, I wanna use `ConnectionView's` output *(which I believe is part of `ConnectionView` object in `AlphaViewController`)*, in `ReportGenerator` to process it and then render data in HTML in `BetaViewController's` view.

I've been messing around to find a solution but haven't been able to figure out anything. I'm not good with delegates.

Please assist me to achieve my goal here. I'm sorry that I can't post the code.

Comment: Can you specify what kind of output is this?? String , image etc.??

Comment: @luckyShubhra output is of ConnectionView type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can pass your output of  `ConnectionView's` from `AlphaViewController` to `BetaViewController` before pushing. When you assign your `BetaViewController` as delegate of `ReportGenerator` pass data i.e  `ConnectionView's` output to `ReportGenerator` and get the `ReportGenerator` to process it and then render data in HTML in `BetaViewController's` view.

It may seem to be complicated in words but it can be achieved.

2. There is also second way much simpler than above using `AppDelegate`. You can declare and define a property in your `AppDelegate` class and access it from anywhere in class.

   ```
   //Interface:

   @interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject  {
      NSString *yourString; // Declare your object
   }

   @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *yourString;
   ...
   @end

   //and in the .m file for the App Delegate     
   @implementation MyAppDelegate

   @synthesize yourString;
   yourString = some string;

   @end

   //You can access the property to save and retrieve your file. You can save 
   MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
   appDelegate.yourString = some NSString;     //..to write
   ```

Yo can read the value in BetaViewController or ReportGenerator as per your requirement as

```
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
someString = appDelegate.myString;  //..to read
```

For for no. of properties you can create Model Class and you access it as defined above.

Comment: AppDelagate method is better because you can access this anywhere in the project.

Comment: @luckyShubhra Thank you so much for this solution. It works flawlessly! However, there is an issue here. When I go back from BetaViewController to AlphaViewController,  output of ConnectionView disappears from screen. It seems like object is completely passed to BetaViewController but not retained anyway by AlphaViewController. Do you have any opinion on why this is happening? I'm fixing it on my own but anyway wanna know the reason for it.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I copied it from my old project not using ARC. Change your property in AppDelegate to strong and nonatomic.