# How to save variable when leaving view

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

In my main view, I am collecting data from two other views. I start in the main view, go to the next view to get the data and go back to the original view. Then I go to the last view and get more data, but when I go back the original data is gone. How do I save it before leaving?

I have tried using `viewWillDisappear` but it wasn't working. Is this a good approach and if so, how do I go about using it?

These are the two pieces of data coming in via segue:

```
var homeTeamName = String ()
var awayTeamName = String ()
```

I do this when I load:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.    }
    HomeName.text = homeTeamName
    HomeImage.image = UIImage(named:homeTeamName)
    AwayName.text = awayTeamName
    AwayImage.image = UIImage(named:awayTeamName)

}
```

`Note:` Everything with away is coming from one view, and everything with home is coming from another.

Now I am storing like this:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set("value", forKey: "homeTeamName")
}
```

Retrieving like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.    
    UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "homeTeamName")
}
```

Still not working.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried the delegate pattern?

Comment: You can use appdelegate for the same you can check my previous ans here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45407423/sharing-data-between-multiple-view-controllers-without-segue-swift-3/45408261#45408261.

Comment: did you fixed this problem?

Comment: Not really I changed the layout so that the views were on one and I just segue the data. All works good, but not with any of these solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot the store variable in the ViewController class when you leave it. Everything probably gets destroyed. As you have to store just two strings, the best way to do is to use UserDefaults.

**Storing**

```
UserDefaults.standard.set("value", forKey: "homeTeamName")
```

**Retrieving**

```
UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "homeTeamName")
```

Use this for printing log

```
print("printingValue\(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "homeTeamName"))")
```

Hope it Helps!

Comment: At what point do I run these lines of code? Would I store in viewWillDisappear and then retrieve at view did load? Also, I will be having up to 20 more strings I want to store. Should I still use the same method?

Comment: Yes you have to store in viewWillDisappear and retrieve at viewDidLoad. Moreover you can store many strings in UserDefaults. You can make a separate class for this purpose or in whichever way you want

Comment: Edited original post. I this what you mean?

Comment: It will surely print the string "value" in viewDidLoad(). You can log it by using print("printingValue\(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "homeTeamName"))")

Comment: Have you printed it?

Comment: It still isn't working. I believe it is storing the value but I am accessing it at the wrong time, or something. I really have no idea what is happening. I tried that line but it gave me an error.

Comment: Can you please tell me the value what it's printing in viewDidLoad ? So please let me know what is the error

Comment: It says Incorrect argument label in call (have 'forKey:', expected 'forKey:') and expected ',' separator. The build crashes.

Comment: Please attach the method where you were getting this error

Comment: WHen I run your line to print it: print("printingValue(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey‌​: "homeTeamName"))")

Comment: Please Check my edited answer and use that line of code to print. It surely work like charm

Comment: Not working. It is putting everything but homeTeamName in commas. Is that the goal?

Comment: `UserDefaults` is not the proper way to pass data between view controllers. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers

Comment: String will be always printed in inverted commas. That's the syntax of it

Comment: @vadian I'm not passing data, I just want to be in the view controller when I go to another one and then come back.

Comment: @AdityaSrivastava Still having the error not sure I understand the goal of the line of code.

Comment: *go to the next view to get the data and go back* actually means *passing data between controllers* ;-)

Comment: Just retrieve and save it in a variable. For Eg : - homeTeamName = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "homeTeamName") . I don't know where is the problem, it's really easy stuff

Answer (score 0):

hey write this for data storing

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let userDefault = UserDefaults.standard
    userDefault.set("value", forKey: "homeTeamName")
}
```

and Write this for Data Retriving Write this

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let userDefault = UserDefaults.standard
    userDefault.value(forKey: "homeTeamName")
}
```

i think it helps u.

Comment: what is .standard?

Comment: it is preference dictionary which saves data and it will delete when u uninstall application. Userdefaults.standard is preference dictionary. and userdefault is object. and write that code into viewwilldisappear and viewwillappear

Comment: I think I found my problem. When I retrieve with in the viewWillAppear, do I need to do this: homeTeamName = userDefault.value(forKey: "homeTeamName")

Comment: yea that is problem and always create object of Prefrance so it is better for Programming.

Comment: also, if the userdefault is set the first time it leaves the view, will it change to the new value of homeTeamName when it leaves a second time?

Comment: it replace with the the second value.

Comment: I don't know how to explain my problem. The view loads and the homeTeamName is blank. I leave to view 2 and when I come back the name has been segued to the original view and works fine. Then I go to view 3 and it disappears. I don't know if this knowledge changes the logic or maybe I have very little understanding of what I'm doing but it isn't working.

Comment: u can any were access user default. which place u need that value u can create a userdefault object and write that code for retraving u can get that value easily.

Comment: Ackkkk This is beyond my knowledge I'm sorry I don't understand. THanks for the help though. I apreciate it